# Why should I unwrap implicitly unwrapped optional?

Tags: swift

I can't understand how string interpolation works in Swift 3. Here are two variables, optional `x` and implicitly unwrapped optional `y`:

```
let x: Int? = 1
let y: Int! = 2
```

Printing of this two optionals looks quite logic:

```
print(x) // Optional(1)
print(y) // 2
```

But why string interpolation works in other way?

```
print("x: \(x)") // x: Optional(1)
print("y: \(y)") // y: Optional(2)
```

Why should I unwrap already unwrapped optional?

```
print("y: \(y!)") // y: 2
```

Let's assume here was used `CustomStringConvertible` protocol that uses `description` property to convert `Int!` to `String`. But why here's no `y: Optional(2)`?

```
print("y: \(y!.description)") // y: 2
print("y: \(y?.description)") // y: Optional("2")
print("y: \(y.description)")  // y: 2
```

Could anyone please explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print`, as part of its own internal workings, unwraps Optionals (the regular, unwrap-yourself kind). String interpolation doesn't do this for you, it just converts whatever you give it.

Here's an explanation of the last example:

- `print("y: \(y!.description)") // y: 2`

  `y` has a type `Int!`, which is explicitly unwrapped, to give its `Int` content. `description` is called on it. `description` returns a `String`. If `y` was nil, this would crash.
- `print("y: \(y?.description)") // y: Optional("2")`

  Optional chaining is used to call `description` on `y`, *only* if it's non-nil. If it's `nil`, then description isn't called in the first place, and the `nil` is propagated. The result of this expression is a `String?`.
- `print("y: \(y.description)")  // y: 2`

  Like case 1, `y` starts as an `Int!`, but is this time *implicitly* unwrapped, to give its `Int` content. `description` is called on it. `description` returns a `String`. If `y` was nil, this would crash.

Comment: Thanks for answer, nice point about `String?` in second case. However, it doesn't explain why `print("y: \(y)")` gives `y: Optional(2)`. Edit: duplicate tag

Comment: It's a shortfall of the type system, as covered in the other question this is linked to. Hopefully it gets fixed, but I won't be losing sleep over it. Just don't use implicitly unwrapped optionals. Apart from IBOutlets and recursive closures, there's almost never a good reason for them.

Comment: There are some reasons, mostly because of Obj-C and Swift interactions. For me it was "A Constant That Cannot Be Defined During Initialization". But that SE-0054 is truly transforms "Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals" to "Schrödinger Optionals".

Comment: I would design around avoiding that sort of two stage initialization. If you give me a concrete case I can help you out